# Checking whether file already exists using while loop with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, loop

How do I check whether a file with a user-defined prefix already exists, using the while loop and if it is a case to request another prefix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`arcpy.Exists()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/exists.htm)**

```
if arcpy.Exists(r"MyFeatureClass"):
    print "Feature Class Exists"
else:
    print "Feature Class Doesn't Exist"
```

Additionally, look into **[`arcpy.CreateUniqueName()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/createuniquename.htm)** to generate a new output name if the one you want to use already exists

```
uniqueName = arcpy.CreateUniqueName(r"MyFeatureClass")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(r"InputFC", uniqueName, "10 Meters")
```

---

Based on what I think your code is doing, try this:

```
sbgfl = "sbg_fluesse" 
bufferwerte = raw_input("Enter buffer in m [split with space bar]") 
bufferwerte_2 = bufferwerte.split() 
praefix = raw_input("Enter prefix") 
for buffer_size in bufferwerte_2:
    uniqueName = arcpy.CreateUniqueName(praefix + str(buffer_size))
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(sbgfl, uniqueName, buffer_size)
```

This will add a suffix number to the end of your output name to make it unique if the output name already exists.

e.g. if `praefix = "roads"` and `buffer_size = 10`, and `roads10` already exists, the `arcpy.CreateUniqueName()` will create a output name of `roads10_0` to make it unique.

And to include a notice to the user that the filename is different:

```
for buffer_size in bufferwerte_2:
    if arcpy.Exists(praefix + str(buffer_size)):
        print "Already exists, changing name"
    uniqueName = arcpy.CreateUniqueName(praefix + str(buffer_size))
    print "Output name = {0}".format(uniqueName)
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(sbgfl, uniqueName, buffer_size)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tasks such as checking for shapefiles or raster data are much more efficient using built-in Python modules. For example:

[`os.path.isfile(path)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)

However, if you need to check for the existance of data within Esri Geodatabases, use the `arcpy.Exists()` command as Midavalo highlights in his answer.